# Computing double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Find $$\iint\limits_D \sqrt{(x-10)^2+y^2}\hspace{1mm}dA$$ where $\{(x, y)\in D \mid x^2+y^2\leq 10^2\}$.

I am not sure how to start, every way I have tried so far, ends up into something ugly.

All Ideas are appreciated

Comment: This is a follow-up to the answer below.  Try letting $t=x-10$ to simplify the integrand.  This gives the region $\{(t,y):(t+10)^2+y^2\le100\}$, which is bounded by the circle $r=-20\cos\theta$ in polar coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

First, it's convenient to shift coordinates so that your integrand is of the form $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. This minimizes the labor of integration. The cost is that the region of integration is shifted off the origin; how do we manage that?

The obvious way of writing a circle of radius $R$ in polar coordinates is $(x,y)=(R\cos\phi,R \sin\phi)$ (i.e. $r(\phi)=R$). This circle will be centered at the origin. But one may also express a circle of radius $R$ for which the origin lies *on* the circle by taking $r(\phi)=2R\cos(\phi-\theta)$ for some angle $\theta$. Which choice of $\theta$ produces your circle? What are your bounds of integration?

Comment: I gave the bounds it is the disk $x^2+y^2\leq 10$

Comment: Not within the coordinate system I'm suggesting!